# Количество записей по образцу

Tags: php, count

Есть код, выдающий общее количество записей в базе:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lekarstvo";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ 
$rowsCount = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк
echo "<p>Получено оценок всего: $rowsCount</p>";

   mysqli_free_result($result);
   } else{
echo "Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы можно было получить количество записей по образцу. Например, Спасибо, или Хорошо и т.д. Каким должен быть код?

Comment: ничего не понятно......

Comment: Код выдает общее количество записей. Мне нужно, чтобы из общего количества были выделены и подсчитаны записи содержащие слово Спасибо, к примеру.

Comment: `содержащие` где? в каком поле?

Comment: поле ball FROM lekarstvo

Comment: @Ralex см ответ

Answer (score 0):

для определения соответствия строки шаблону в SQL используется функция `LIKE`

Также для того чтобы не учитывать регистр букв - приведем значение нужного поля к нижнему регистру с помощью функции `LOWER`

Запрос будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM lekarstvo WHERE LOWER(ball) LIKE '%отлично%'
```

**Замечание:**
т.к. значение поля приведено к нижнему регистру - в шаблоне строка так же должна быть в нижнем регистре, в противном случае функция **гарантировано не найдет совпадений**

**и в коде**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lekarstvo WHERE LOWER(ball) LIKE '%отлично%';";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ 
    $rowsCount = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк
    echo "<p>Получено оценок всего: $rowsCount</p>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

---

**Имеем таблицу**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Результат фильтрации в бд**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Результат выполнения скрипта**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показывает 0, хотя в таблице есть 10 записей.

Comment: @Ralex и в них всех есть спасибо?

Comment: @Ralex приведите значения таблицы в вопросе

Comment: Я чуть поторопился. Не Спасибо, а Отлично, но в коде я все исправил, все равно - 0.
1 - Хорошо
2 - Отлично
3 - Отлично
и т.д.

Comment: @Ralex  , вы отлично в шаблоне как указывали? `'%отлично%' ` или `'%Отлично%'`? или еще как?

Comment: @Ralex я поправил в ответе (попробуйте скопировать из него)

Comment: Да по-разному...

Comment: @Ralex я поправил в коде и написал замечание. Попробуйте снова и отпишитесь

Comment: Без изменений пока что - 0

Comment: @Ralex, значит вы определенно что-то недоговариваете или не так применяете.

Comment: @Ralex, я добавил таблицу, скопировал скрипт и протестировал - см в ответе внизу. все отлично работает

Comment: Но значение поля в таблице - Отлично.

Comment: @Ralex не понял последнего комментария

Comment: В localhost у меня тоже всё работает. Не работает в weeb. Хотя общее количество считает, значит связь с таблицей есть.
В таблице определенное количество значений и пользователь выбирает одно из них -  Отлично, Хорошо, Нормально и т.д.
т.е. Отлично всегда с большой буквы.

Comment: @Ralex ну если на localhost все работает, то наверное у вас с чем-то другим возникли проблемы в web...например там другая база данных, другие параметры подключения или нет той таблицы, или нет тех значений

Comment: @Ralex, вам бы в `select` е в `option`ах value прописать циферками и их сохранять и не мучаться со строками...но это немного другой вопрос.

Comment: Значения в таблице есть. Таблица есть. Нет ключа к записям. 
Ладно, остыну пока. Выхода из тупика не вижу. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Ralex, если ответ с запросом помог - отметьте его как верный

Comment: @Ralex, если не знаете куда копать - можете мне написать в тг (он в профиле указан) - посмотрю что к чему и помогу

Comment: @Ralex, эх @Ralex)), так вы галочку и не поставили))))